# ¿cómo hago para que no se resetee mi código al refrescarse la página en Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo con `Tampermonkey` un código dentro de una página web para que al pulsar un botón se vayan clickando distintos botones de la página.

El problema es que con cada click se pasa a otra página y parece que se resetea el script ya que después de hacer el primer click y pasar a la siguiente página ya no se ejecuta más código, ni otro click ni un alert ni nada.

He probado usando un `setTimeout`, ya que hace años hice un programa parecido y funcionaba con él, pero no sirve tampoco, simplemente al recargarse la página ya no funciona ningún código del script.
Pongo aquí el script

```
    / ==UserScript==
    // @name        script1
    // @namespace   script1
    // @include    *pagina.com*
    // @version     1
    // @grant        none
    // ==/UserScript==

    //se inserta el botón 
    document.getElementById('menuTable').insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<input type='button' id='boton' value='IR' />");
    document.getElementById("boton").addEventListener('click',vamos,false);


    function vamos(){


    var boton1;
    boton1 = document.evaluate(
    "//*[@class='system_action']",
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null);
    boton1.snapshotItem(0).click();

    setTimeout(function(){alert("hola");}, 6000);//esta instrucción ya no se ejecuta después de actualizar la página con la anterior instrucción
     
    }
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo hacer que siga ejecutándose el código?